# 2 servers with infiniband cards and one IB switch i want to use the Ip Over IB

Tags: infiniband

I have 2 super Micro servers with XCP installed i have 2 Infiniband cards on them, i have IB switch also, Now i want to connect Both servers with IP O IB, How can i do that, if i am using Infiniband i need to disable the Ethernet Card.

How can i connect Both servers over Infiniband please advise?

Comment: Duplicate question missing therefore I vote to reopen.

Comment: BTW, Infiniband support in the kernel for Centos 5.x which Xen Server is based on (not sure about XCP) is actually broken.  It might be possible to get it working but some header files are broken in that particular release.

Comment: I think you'll still need Ethernet, leave it enabled.  If you do manage to get the drivers for the IB into the kernel working you'll also need to configure this by hand from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The IB stuff has nothing to do with Ethernet, so steer clear of that. You don't mention what OS you're using, but the OFED includes IPoIB (which works on Windows, Linux, and FreeBSD).

Comment: i am using Cantos 5.X, I am really confused how to use Infiniband Network because i am new to Infiniband , i search in the internet for example configuration. But i never find any good tutorial can you please help me on this configuration .

Comment: [This site has some really good walk-throughs to get you running](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fperformance%2Fhowtos%2Frhelbonding.htm). If you're still having issues after following those ask another question here. If the question relates to more "basic" network usage you might also consider [Unix.SE] (who deal with hobby and home usage of Linux).

Comment: Thanks Chris,   But Infiniband Need customization, as i am new to this technologies so i need some help from some one, Please if you anybody made this implementation before Please help me with your suggestions